# Why is `user-full-name' returning “”?

Tags: elisp

I'm running Emacs on a linux system and the function `user-full-name`,
when called with no arguments, always returns an empty string.

**How can I fix this?**

I assume it's something I need to configure on my user account, maybe
an environment variable.

*(The variable `user-login-name` works fine.)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function `user-full-name` with no arguments returns the value of the variable `user-full-name`.  This variable is initialised:

- to the value of the environment variable `NAME` if it is defined; or
- to the Gecos field of the passwd entry.

Therefore, you can do one of the following:

- set the Gecos field of your passwd entry using one of the `chfn` or `usermod` commands;
- set your user name in the `NAME` environment variable in your shell's initialisation file;
- set the `user-full-name` variable in your Emacs' initialisation file.

Answer (score 4):

Google is your friend. =/

```
$ chfn -f "Full Name"
```

Comment: Tsk Tsk, Malabarba.

Comment: @Gilles is that better? ☺